# Remove object on collision with ball

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I know you can `fillRect` right? And you can `clearRect`. But what happens if there's an animation and you have to remove an object although it would be redrawn from `setInterval`. How would you remove the fillRect?

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;


var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
ctx.fill();
  } else {
ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawRect = function (x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
}

var Object = function (xPos, yPos) {
this.x = xPos;
this.y = yPos;
}
// The Ball constructor
var Ball = function () {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 0;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.radius = 10;
};

// Update the ball's position based on its speed
Ball.prototype.move = function () {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 11) {
this.x = 11;
  } else if (this.x > width - 11) {
this.x = width - 11;
  } else if (this.y < 11) {
this.y = 11;
  } else if (this.y > height - 11) {
this.y = height - 11;
  }
};

// Draw the ball at its current position
Ball.prototype.draw = function () {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true, "Black");
};

Object.prototype.draw = function () {
drawRect(this.x, this.y, "Black")
}

Object.prototype.drawKey = function (color) {
  drawRect(this.x, this.y, "Yellow")
}

Object.prototype.checkCollision = function (direction) {
return (ball.x-ball.radius < this.x + 20)
  && (ball.x+ball.radius > this.x)
  && (ball.y-ball.radius < this.y + 20)
  && (ball.y+ball.radius > this.y)
  ;
}

function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

ball.draw();
object1.draw("Blue");
object2.draw();
object3.draw();
object4.draw();
object5.draw();
key.drawKey();

ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function simulate() {
  for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
var prev_ball_x = ball.x;
var prev_ball_y = ball.y;
ball.move();
// handle collision here
if (object1.checkCollision() || object2.checkCollision() || object3.checkCollision() || object4.checkCollision() || object5.checkCollision()) {
    ball.setDirection('stop');
    // reset ball's position so they do not overlap
    ball.x = prev_ball_x;
    ball.y = prev_ball_y;
}

if (key.checkCollision()) {
  ball.x = prev_ball_x;
  ball.y = prev_ball_y;
}

  }

  $("body").keyup(function (event) {
  ball.setDirection('stop'); 
})
}

setInterval(function () {
// separate drawing and simulating phases
simulate();
draw();
}, 30);

// Set the ball's direction based on a string
Ball.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
  if (direction === "up") {
 this.xSpeed = 0;
 this.ySpeed = -1;
  } else if (direction === "down") {
 this.xSpeed = 0;
 this.ySpeed = 1;
  } else if (direction === "left") {
 this.xSpeed = -1;
 this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
 this.xSpeed = 1;
 this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
this.xSpeed = 0;
 this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
};

// Create the ball object
var ball = new Ball();
var object1 = new Object(50, 0);
var object2 = new Object(50, 20);
var object3 = new Object(50, 40);
var object4 = new Object(50, 60);
var object5 = new Object(50, 80);
var key = new Object(70, 70);

// An object to convert keycodes into action names
var keyActions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

// The keydown handler that will be called for every keypress
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
```

You move around a ball with your arrow keys. When I collide with the yellow block, I want it to disappear. Using clearRect would not work simply because it would be redrawn in the setInterval. How would I make it disappear?

Comment: It's more portable as a runnable code snippet without the doctype tags and such. For example you could copy it to your own answer or copy paste it into jsfiddle without problems. If you'd like me to rollback the edit, I will do that.

Comment: @Shashank Is right, having a fiddle or more preferred, a snippet. Makes it much easier for us to re-produce your code and make the changes for our solution. For example, I simply need to click "Copy snippet to answer" and modify it. With the entire source I would have to copy, make modifications, separated the code sections, etc... It's just a way to make it more convent for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you have several items in a game you place them into a sort of `objects` array, then when you draw you loop through and call `.draw()` on each item. Doing it this way allows you to remove items you do not want (such as `key`), and as such it will no longer be drawn. In your case one thing we could do (assuming there is only a single key) is give your `ball` a `hasKey` property. And on collision set it from `false` to `true`. Then inside draw, if you wish to also remove the collisions you would do `!ball.hasKey && key.checkCollision()` inside your collision conditional for the key:

```
if(!ball.hasKey) key.drawKey();
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;


var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
ctx.fill();
  } else {
ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawRect = function (x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
}

var Object = function (xPos, yPos) {
this.x = xPos;
this.y = yPos;
}
// The Ball constructor
var Ball = function () {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 0;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.radius = 10;
  this.hasKey = false;
};

// Update the ball's position based on its speed
Ball.prototype.move = function () {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 11) {
this.x = 11;
  } else if (this.x > width - 11) {
this.x = width - 11;
  } else if (this.y < 11) {
this.y = 11;
  } else if (this.y > height - 11) {
this.y = height - 11;
  }
};

// Draw the ball at its current position
Ball.prototype.draw = function () {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true, "Black");
};

Object.prototype.draw = function () {
drawRect(this.x, this.y, "Black")
}

Object.prototype.drawKey = function (color) {
  drawRect(this.x, this.y, "Yellow")
}

Object.prototype.checkCollision = function (direction) {
return (ball.x-ball.radius < this.x + 20)
  && (ball.x+ball.radius > this.x)
  && (ball.y-ball.radius < this.y + 20)
  && (ball.y+ball.radius > this.y)
  ;
}

function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

ball.draw();
object1.draw("Blue");
object2.draw();
object3.draw();
object4.draw();
object5.draw();
if(!ball.hasKey) key.drawKey();

ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function simulate() {
  for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
var prev_ball_x = ball.x;
var prev_ball_y = ball.y;
ball.move();
// handle collision here
if (object1.checkCollision() || object2.checkCollision() || object3.checkCollision() || object4.checkCollision() || object5.checkCollision()) {
    ball.setDirection('stop');
    // reset ball's position so they do not overlap
    ball.x = prev_ball_x;
    ball.y = prev_ball_y;
}

if (!ball.hasKey && key.checkCollision()) {
  ball.x = prev_ball_x;
  ball.y = prev_ball_y;
  ball.hasKey = true;
}

  }

  $("body").keyup(function (event) {
  ball.setDirection('stop'); 
})
}

setInterval(function () {
// separate drawing and simulating phases
simulate();
draw();
}, 30);

// Set the ball's direction based on a string
Ball.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
  if (direction === "up") {
 this.xSpeed = 0;
 this.ySpeed = -1;
  } else if (direction === "down") {
 this.xSpeed = 0;
 this.ySpeed = 1;
  } else if (direction === "left") {
 this.xSpeed = -1;
 this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
 this.xSpeed = 1;
 this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
this.xSpeed = 0;
 this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
};

// Create the ball object
var ball = new Ball();
var object1 = new Object(50, 0);
var object2 = new Object(50, 20);
var object3 = new Object(50, 40);
var object4 = new Object(50, 60);
var object5 = new Object(50, 80);
var key = new Object(70, 70);

// An object to convert keycodes into action names
var keyActions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

// The keydown handler that will be called for every keypress
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I always use integers, forget the booleans alot